# List Comprehension with Varible Length Outputs

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to construct a list of all possible permutations from another predefined list. I am hoping to use list comprehensions, but am open to other suggestions.

The issue I am having is that the output for the elements of the list could be any user defined, positive integer in length and I have yet to come across anything that points me in a direction on how to automate that (if it is possible).

```
bases = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']
```

So if I want an output of 3 I would need

```
[x+y+z for x in bases for y in bases for z in bases]
```

and for an output of 4 I would need

```
[w+x+y+z for w in bases for x in bases for y in bases for z in bases]
```

Comment: "Permutations" refers to rearrangements of the input (without repeating elements). Based on your examples, this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: If you really want to see what it looks like as a 'list comprehension', this would work: `product = lambda items, l: [i+j for i in items for j in product(items, l-1)] if l-1 else items`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.permutations(bases)))
# => [('A', 'C', 'G', 'T'), ('A', 'C', 'T', 'G'), ('A', 'G', 'C', 'T'), ('A', 'G', 'T', 'C'), ('A', 'T', 'C', 'G'), ('A', 'T', 'G', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'G', 'T'), ('C', 'A', 'T', 'G'), ('C', 'G', 'A', 'T'), ('C', 'G', 'T', 'A'), ('C', 'T', 'A', 'G'), ('C', 'T', 'G', 'A'), ('G', 'A', 'C', 'T'), ('G', 'A', 'T', 'C'), ('G', 'C', 'A', 'T'), ('G', 'C', 'T', 'A'), ('G', 'T', 'A', 'C'), ('G', 'T', 'C', 'A'), ('T', 'A', 'C', 'G'), ('T', 'A', 'G', 'C'), ('T', 'C', 'A', 'G'), ('T', 'C', 'G', 'A'), ('T', 'G', 'A', 'C'), ('T', 'G', 'C', 'A')]
```

Comprehension is the bad tool for the job (at least by themselves) because you need recursion (or at least what recursion flattens down to) to properly take care of the variable-length list.

**EDIT:** Now, your text says "permutations", which is when elements don't repeat, just shuffle. Your code indicates you might be thinking of Cartesian product, where each position is independently chosen from the set; in which case you want `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.product(bases, repeat=3)))
# => [('A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'G'), ('A', 'A', 'T'), ('A', 'C', 'A'), ('A', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'T'), ('A', 'G', 'A'), ('A', 'G', 'C'), ('A', 'G', 'G'), ('A', 'G', 'T'), ('A', 'T', 'A'), ('A', 'T', 'C'), ('A', 'T', 'G'), ('A', 'T', 'T'), ('C', 'A', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'C'), ('C', 'A', 'G'), ('C', 'A', 'T'), ('C', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'G'), ('C', 'C', 'T'), ('C', 'G', 'A'), ('C', 'G', 'C'), ('C', 'G', 'G'), ('C', 'G', 'T'), ('C', 'T', 'A'), ('C', 'T', 'C'), ('C', 'T', 'G'), ('C', 'T', 'T'), ('G', 'A', 'A'), ('G', 'A', 'C'), ('G', 'A', 'G'), ('G', 'A', 'T'), ('G', 'C', 'A'), ('G', 'C', 'C'), ('G', 'C', 'G'), ('G', 'C', 'T'), ('G', 'G', 'A'), ('G', 'G', 'C'), ('G', 'G', 'G'), ('G', 'G', 'T'), ('G', 'T', 'A'), ('G', 'T', 'C'), ('G', 'T', 'G'), ('G', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'A', 'A'), ('T', 'A', 'C'), ('T', 'A', 'G'), ('T', 'A', 'T'), ('T', 'C', 'A'), ('T', 'C', 'C'), ('T', 'C', 'G'), ('T', 'C', 'T'), ('T', 'G', 'A'), ('T', 'G', 'C'), ('T', 'G', 'G'), ('T', 'G', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'A'), ('T', 'T', 'C'), ('T', 'T', 'G'), ('T', 'T', 'T')]
```

Comment: Given the examples, what OP wants is actually product and not permutations.

Comment: @interjay: Good point. However, not sure if I trust the code, so let's give both options.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it without itertools. It's just a recursive function which returns a list of strings.

```
def product(items, length):
    if length == 1:
        return items

    combos = []
    for i in items:
        for j in product(items, length-1):
            combos.append(i+j)

    return combos

print(product('ACGT', 3))

#>>> ['AAA', 'AAC', 'AAG', 'AAT', 'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACG', 'ACT' ...
```